# Possible to stop redirect after submitting POST request to Facebook graph?

Tags: facebook, post, facebook-opengraph

Quick background: I've created a basic Facebook app so users can "like" a post from a website outside of Facebook. Users authenticate, are redirected with their `access_token` which is gathered by some JS and inserted into the form via hidden field and passed to the `POST` request. (Not necessarily relevant, but I also use some JS to automatically submit the 'like' after the user is redirected to the site from Facebook.)

After the HTTP request is sent (and is successful), the user is redirected to the response page, rendering only "true" printed on the screen. Is there a way to stop this redirect? I've set up some JS to swap out some `div` content once the form is submitted, but I can't seem to stop them from being directed away.

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

**HTML Excerpt**

```
    <!-- *Authentication Section* -->
    <div id="submit_like">
      <form>
       <a id="facebook-authentication" href="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?type=user_agent&client_id=[MY_APP_ID]&redirect_uri=[MY_POST-AUTHORIZATION_REDIRECT_URL]&scope=offline_access,publish_stream">
       <div id="facebook-authentication-button">
       START THE VOTE!
       </div>
       </a>
      </form>
    </div>

<!-- After Authentication, this form is submitted -->
<form id="likeform" method="POST" action="https://graph.facebook.com/[FACEBOOK_ID]/likes"  >
  <input id="AuthCode" name="access_token" type="hidden" value="123">
</form>
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you cannot use PHP?

Comment: @phwd Yes - quite simple. I don't know/use PHP. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the jQuery [`.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) method to submit the form without any page redirection. In your case:

```
$.post("https://graph.facebook.com/[FACEBOOK_ID]/likes", $("#likeform").serialize()).done(function(data){

    // redirect to new page or do nothing to stay put.
    alert(data); //Show the returned value

});
```

The [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) helper function takes the form input and creates a string in URL-encoded notation. This string is sent as the parameter, which will contain the access_token hidden form input.

Just as a reminder, be sure to have jQuery included.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
```